# Not allow space as a first character and allow only letters using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jquery for the name validation I have tried a code which is given below

```
$("#contactname").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which < 97 /* a */ || e.which > 122 && (e.which < 65 || e.which > 90)) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }         
});
```

The above code is working fine to allow only letters and not allow numbers but its not allow space.So what i want is it should allow only letters (both small and capital letters) then it should not allow numbers and special characters and also accept space except as a first character And please tell me how to restrict when copy paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the HTML5 attribute `pattern`? See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) on it for more information.

Using a regex of `^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*` seems to cover your requirements.

So something like:

```html
<div>Username:</div>
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*" title="Can use upper and lower letters, and spaces but must not start with a space" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
 $("#contactname").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.charCode;
        if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
 });
```

Comment: But its allowing space at starting

Answer (score 0):

I finally got solution for this issue

```
$("#contactname").keypress(function(e) {
       if (e.which === 32 && !this.value.length) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
       var inputValue = event.charCode;
       if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)){
           event.preventDefault();
       }          
   });
```

This code working fine for my exact need

Answer (score 0):

This solution work best for me:

```
$("#nama").keypress(function(e) {
   if (e.which === 32 && !this.value.length) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32);        
});
```

Not allowing white space at first keypress. And also not allowing any special characters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* First character space not allowed in text field */
$ = jQuery;
$('#billing_house_no').keyup(function(e) {
  var strg = this.value;
  var firstChar = strg.charAt(0);
  if ((firstChar == " ")||(firstChar == "&nbsp;")||(strg == "")) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g,'');  
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.