# Not allow space as a first input character in input field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a name input filed that takes all the characters including space. I want to use regular expression to not allow first character to be a blank space. User must enter at least one valid character before they are allowed to enter space. 
Thank you for you help.

Comment: The pattern `^\S.*$` should meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen, what I need to add if I only want to allow letters not numbers and special characters. Thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365256/not-allow-space-as-a-first-character-and-allow-only-letters-using-jquery This should help

Comment: Great thanks Mohit

Comment: alternatively you can use ^\S[a-zA-Z ]+$

Answer (score 5):

> I want to use regular expression to not allow first character to be a
>   blank space.

Instead of using regex you can just capture keys in the input and prevent space from being inserted when it's the first character entered.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (this.value.length === 0 && e.which === 32) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to implement something like this? The first character can never be a space, it has to be some char, after the first char, then it can have infinite number of spaces after it.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("demo");

// A function to encapsulate your logic. 
const process = e => {
  const v = el.value.toString().replace(/\ /g, '');

  // Must have length > 0 before the space bar will do anything. 
  if (v.length == 0 && e.which == 32) e.preventDefault();

  // First char must not be a space. 
  else if (el.value[0] == ' ') el.value = el.value.replace(/\ /, '');
};

// Do whatever here. 
const onChange = () => {
  el.onkeydown = process;
  el.onkeyup = process;
};


// Lazy on ready.. 
setTimeout(onChange, 100);
```

```html
<input id="demo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `trim` to validate the extra space and then see if atleast a character is added or not.

```js
let str = "  ";
console.log(str);

if(!str.trim()) {
  console.log("At least a character required");
} else {
  console.log(str);
}

let correctStr = " a ";
if(!correctStr.trim()) {
  console.log("At least a character required");
} else {
  console.log(correctStr);
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the help guys and sorry for my bad english :-/
Is it not possible do this only with the HTML5 pattern-attribute?
Trying clearify what i want:
When someone type his/her fullname, testing if the field is NOT started with 1 or more blank spaces, but between the names spaces are allowed!
When the input field started with blank spaces show error-message!