# HTML5 pattern: Check text field start not start with blank space

Tags: html

Try check if input filed start with blank space, after testing e few hours and searching and testing a lot of patterns, found on internet, it doesn't work.

What i want: check if html5 input field start with character (no blank space), but in the text are blank spaces allowed.

At the moment the best solution i found, but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" class="naamveld" placeholder="Fullname" pattern="^\S+$" required>
```

Someone can help me with this 'simple' thing?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sorry but your grammar is hard to read....

Comment: Couldn't you just trim() the input on form submission?

Comment: exactly i was going to say that

Comment: Here's the answer to your question if you're adamant about doing it this way: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020591/not-allow-space-as-a-first-input-character-in-input-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not allow space as a first input character in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020591/not-allow-space-as-a-first-input-character-in-input-field)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript regex - no white space at beginning + allow space in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973669/javascript-regex-no-white-space-at-beginning-allow-space-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular expression like this:

```
^[^-\s][\w\s-]+$
```

like it is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973669/javascript-regex-no-white-space-at-beginning-allow-space-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you said you wanted to remove all the whitespaces in the input, try this:

```html
<input type="text" class="naamveld" placeholder="Fullname" required onkeydown="this.value = this.value.trim()" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.trim()">
```

If you try adding spaces at the beginning and end of the input, it will remove them.

### How it works

The input has two attributes, (`onkeydown` and `onkeyup`) these functions will perform when the input receives a keyup or keydown, and will remove all whitespaces from the value of the input using `this.value = this.value.trim()`

If you want to learn more on how the `trim()` function works, you can [go here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-strip-in-javascript/).

Comment: OP is asking to check, not to remove. And to do this using the html5 pattern attribute. So he is looking for the correct regexp to be put in the pattern attribute, not to trim the field value

Comment: oh... sorry I thought this was the question because the grammar was really bad and everyone in comments was suggesting to use `.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, again sorry for my bad english :-s
I want thanks everyone for all this useful info. When looking to the answers and solutions, with our help this is the solution (see pattern):

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\S.*$" ...>
```

*Checked if input field started with blank space(s).*

This is for me the best and simplest solution :-)